# How to prevent inputing voltage into the output of a dc/dc converter

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I want to know how to prevent accidentally inputting my 60V DC supply into the output of my DC/DC converter.

The two scenarios could be:

1. That I accidentally insert the 60V DC into the output of DC/DC instead of the input
2. I have the input connected to 60V DC and the output is 12V DC as normal. However, the 12V DC output cable accidentally touches the 60V DC busbar.

This is more for like industry specs. So in case a 12V output wire becomes lose and then makes contact with the 60V DC busbar. Most likely will not happen but if it does how to I prevent the 60V DC from going into the output of the DC/DC

What can I do in terms of "circuit protection" to prevent this from damaging my circuit?

I imagine is scenario one will cook the DC/DC.

[image]

Comment: How to prevent? Label the connections? Use connectors that don't fit unless connected correctly?

Comment: @Justme I see I havent explained this how I would have wanted too. I have updated the question to hopefully make it more clear on what I mean

Comment: Engineers are expected to avoid connecting wires the wrong way. Using polarized connectors can help (but if you assemble the connector, you still have to make sure you do THAT right). To avoid shorting to a busbar, cover the busbar or put a barrier between areas you are handling and the bus bar. I often tape over things if I think there is an unusually high probability of an accidental short. Products need to be designed so it is very difficult for consumers to short or misconnect things. But during bring-up and debug, engineers just have to be very careful and use temporary barriers.

Comment: How to prevent wire from becoming loose and touching 60V? Zip lock ties, heat shrink, glue? Even if a wire comes loose, it should not be able to move and short circuit anything.

Comment: For (1) use different and incompatible connectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 12V output cable shorts to the 60V DC bus bar, then there's nothing you can do, the output of the converter will get 60V, and any loads connected to it which prefer living with 12V will blow.

Now both MOSFETs in your buck DC-DC converter should of course be rated for more than 60V, because they handle that voltage everyday, so they should be fine.

If the output capacitors are rated for 16V and get 60V they will have a bad day. So you could consider using output caps with a suitable surge voltage rating to make sure they survive.

Besides that, it's more about the behavior of the DC-DC chip.

If 60V is connected to the output with the input disconnected, and it is a buck converter, then it will be powered through the body diode of the top MOSFET and start up almost normally.

Then the DC-DC controller chip will probably panic because output voltage is way too high. If it's a non-synchronous buck, with a diode, it'll just turn off the top FET and sit there, no harm done. If it's a synchronous buck it will probably try to lower output voltage by sucking energy from the output into the input, which turns it into a boost converter, and may cause input voltage to rise until something blows, or the bottom FET will blow due to overcurrent. The chip's current sense amp could also stop working if its common mode is out of range.

Anyway. Rather than spending extra budget on this, I'd recommend spending the budget on clearly labeling "INPUT" and "OUTPUT", with polarity, and specs clearly written on a label that's actually readable, black and white not clear blue on light grey, etc.

Comment: I think I will also get a DC/DC that has over-voltage protection, so as soon as the DC/DC sees the 60V DC at its output the over-voltage protection will kick in and shut down the output.

Answer (score -1):

The question seems strange.

1. Make sure the connectors for different voltages are incompatible.
2. Ensure that inputs use male pins and outputs use female sockets.
3. Secure all cables properly using crimped terminals.
4. Don't make adjustments on live equipment.
5. Protect the busbar with acrylic or polycarbonate covers with holes for voltage probes.

[image]

*Image source: [Google image search](https://dinrailterminalblock.com/products/dinkle-combiner-dk2-5n-or-with-10-pole-jumper).*

6. Don't use bare busbars. Use industrial finger-proof DIN rail terminals with jumper bars.

Answer (score -1):

Use a different colour wire for 60V and for 12V colour the connectors to match.

Place a cover over the 60V bus bar to prevent stray conductors from falling on it.